# XCode 6.1.1 Swift breakpoint getting skipped, printing to console works fine

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift, breakpoints

I have encountered this issue few times already, and wondering what is wrong there? or this is simply Xcode bug.

Breakpoint is skipped in viewDidLoad, however printing to console works.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set up user data if exist
    let User = _UserManager!.currentUser!

    if (User.containsDetails()) {

        println("DUCK!")


    } else {
        //no details given yet
        ageSlider.value = 2.0
        incomeSlider.value = 2.0
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with version 6.1. It seems to be a bug, usually closing Xcode and starting it again solves the problem.